# Why is my foreach loop not looping through and populating array?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a class that loops through a directory (5 images) and converts each image to base64 format and fills an array. However, it seems that the foreach loop only loops through once. There is 5 images in the directory, so it should have 5 iterations and the array should be 5 different images as well.

PHP

```
require_once "Results.php";
require_once "ImageHelper.php";

class IntroImageHelper {
    public static function GetImages()
    {
      $results = new Results();
      $results->IntroImages = Array();
      $dir = new DirectoryIterator("img/");
      $ImageExists = false;
      foreach($dir as $file)
      {
        if($file->isFile())
        {
          $ImageExists = $file->__toString();
          break;
        }
      }

      if($ImageExists)
      {
        $tempImage = new Results();
        $tempImage->ImageName = $ImageExists;
        $tempImage->ImageData = ImageHelperIntroSlides::DownloadImage($file);
        array_push($results->IntroImages, $tempImage);
      }

       return $results;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{"IntroImages: [
    {"ImageName": "image.png",
     "ImageDate": "base64imagedata"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You're not calling `array_push()` inside the loop.

Answer (score 4):

Using a `break` statement will stop loops. You can use `continue` to skip the rest of the execution of the current iteration and go to to the next iteration, but in your case just omitting the `break` will fix your problem:

```
foreach($dir as $file) {
    if($file->isFile()) {
      $ImageExists = $file->__toString();
    }
}
```

In your case, a bunch of your code is outside of the loop when it should be inside:

```
foreach($dir as $file) {
    if($file->isFile()) {
      $ImageExists = $file->__toString();
    }
    if($ImageExists) {
        $tempImage = new Results();
        $tempImage->ImageName = $ImageExists;
        $tempImage->ImageData = ImageHelperIntroSlides::DownloadImage($file);
        array_push($results->IntroImages, $tempImage);
    }
}
```

But you can also combine those two statements:

```
foreach($dir as $file) {
    if($file->isFile()) {
        $tempImage = new Results();
        $tempImage->ImageName = $file->__toString();
        $tempImage->ImageData = ImageHelperIntroSlides::DownloadImage($file);
        array_push($results->IntroImages, $tempImage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Scopey! I didnt fully grasp the logic of a break. I assumed that it would temporarily stop, run the rest of the code, then come back and finish the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have the break in the for loop? That will quit the loop...

Comment: This is a question, not an answer.

Comment: it's a question-answer. It only goes once through because of the break. I was trying to point that out :)

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what `break` will do, it will **break out** of the loop.

If you need to just flag a value, remove the break and let the iterations continue.

But in your case you did not need to, for a check change your loop to the following:

```
foreach($dir as $file)
{
    if($file->isFile())
    {
        $tempImage = new Results();
        $tempImage->ImageName = $file->__toString();
        $tempImage->ImageData = ImageHelperIntroSlides::DownloadImage($file);
        array_push($results->IntroImages, $tempImage);
    }
}
```